# Extjs issue with using a JSON file to populate a grid

Tags: json, extjs, extjs4

I am trying to use a JSON file to populate a grid but the JSON file is complex.

Below is my JavaScript File and below that is link to my JSON file. Note that the fields I am experimenting with in the JSON file are located at the top.

I have tried everything but I can only get 'server_time' if I remove the 'root' and 'record' from the 'reader', so that proves the it works on some level but I can't get anything else no matter which configuration I try.

Please help me solve this issue. Thanks in Advance!

### Link to JSON File [LINK](http://julianjosephs.com/company_list.json)

### ExtJS Code

```
Ext.onReady(function(){

    Ext.define('Jobs', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
        fields: [
            {name: 'op_comm_status'},
            {name: 'job_category_level_two'},
            {name: 'op_description'}
        ]
    });

    var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        model: 'Jobs',
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url : 'results/company_list.json',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                root: 'jobs',
                record: 'job'
            }
        }
    });

    store.load();

    var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
        store: store,
        columns: [{
            header: 'Status',
            dataIndex: 'op_comm_status'
        },{
            header: 'Category Level Two',
            dataIndex: 'job_category_level_two'
        },{
            header: 'Description',
            dataIndex: 'op_description'
        }]
    });

    grid.render(Ext.getBody());
})
```

Comment: Have you tried removing the record from reader? According to the API, it is often not necessary.

Comment: One more idea: Try indicating that jobs contains an array of job even though there is only one job. Put [ ] around {job:...} in the JSON.

Comment: I'm not sure that's such a good approach as I get the JSON  with PHP through a 3rd party API

Answer (score 0):

Not really a solution, I switched to XML instead and had it working within 5 minutes

Answer (score 0):

try below code :

```
var proxy = new Ext.data.HttpProxy({url: "your url"});
var reader = new Ext.data.JsonReader({
        root: 'rows',
        totalProperty: 'count',
        id: 'id'    });
var store = new Ext.data.Store({
        proxy: proxy,
        reader: reader,
        remoteSort: true
    });
```

you can include other attribute as required.